# Greek SpellChecking with texmaker

Tags: texmaker, languages, spelling, spellchecking

I want to use greek spellechecking with texMaker. They provide a resource for additional dictionaries for multiple languages, but the greek one doesn't seem to work. I downloaded and placed in the proper folder the greek .dic and .aff files but the spellcheck doesnt recognise any word as correctly written.

Comment: Dear George what is your Pc configuration, windows?

Comment: I think I found a solution for your issue. Do you still need it?